# Install GYM openAI win 10/7

Tags: windows, installation, openai-gym

I am new here and following this guide (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-openai-gym-in-a-windows-environment-338969e24d30) it is not possible to install the open AI, there is always an error when compiling.
Tried different versions of anaconda ... python version ... adding compiler to path...
Any help would be appreciated!

Collecting git+https://github.com/Kojoley/atari-py.git
  Cloning https://github.com/Kojoley/atari-py.git to c:\users...\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-ppc4tb1g
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from atari-py==0.1.7) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from atari-py==0.1.7) (1.11.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: atari-py
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for atari-py ... error
...
  Iatari_py\ale_interface\src\external\TinyMT -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include -c atari_py\ale_interface\src\emucore\Random.cxx -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\atari_py\ale_interface\src\emucore\random.o
  In file included from atari_py\ale_interface\src\emucore\Random.cxx:26:0:
  atari_py\ale_interface\src\external/TinyMT/tinymt32.h: In function 'void tinymt32_next_state(tinymt32_t*)':
  atari_py\ale_interface\src\external/TinyMT/tinymt32.h:35:42: error: 'UINT32_C' was not declared in this scope
   #define TINYMT32_MASK UINT32_C(0x7fffffff)
                                            ^
  atari_py\ale_interface\src\external/TinyMT/tinymt32.h:84:30: note: in expansion of macro 'TINYMT32_MASK'
       x = (random->status[0] & TINYMT32_MASK)
                                ^
  atari_py\ale_interface\src\external/TinyMT/tinymt32.h: In function 'float tinymt32_temper_conv(tinymt32_t*)':
  atari_py\ale_interface\src\external/TinyMT/tinymt32.h:141:29: error: 'UINT32_C' was not declared in this scope
          | UINT32_C(0x3f800000);
                               ^
  atari_py\ale_interface\src\external/TinyMT/tinymt32.h: In function 'float tinymt32_temper_conv_open(tinymt32_t*)':
  atari_py\ale_interface\src\external/TinyMT/tinymt32.h:168:29: error: 'UINT32_C' was not declared in this scope
          | UINT32_C(0x3f800001);
                               ^
  error: command 'C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below steps:-
To get the command prompt for installation
-just go to start and choose anaconda prompt
-type your installation command

## To install open ai gym-

```
pip install gym
```

For more dependencies installation,please follow http://gym.openai.com/docs/

Hope this helps.